# can you make my life easier working this way? (large code base and patching issue)

Tags: php, git, large-data

So I am working on a really large code base, more than 3000 files, more than 1 million lines of code and more than 500+ tables.

Though that is not really the issue. The issue here is, when a new feature is required, I work on it locally on my machine and when the time comes to update/patch our live production:

1. I ssh to our prod server
2. I navigate to the directory, and open the file to patch
3. I copy and paste??? OMG

Anyway, here is my take, please suggest if you guys have alternatives or more comfortable of doing this

1. First, we migrate to GIT. (we're in SVN)
2. Everytime we make release, we branch out in our git repo, and then clone a new copy in our prod server (right now we do a branch in svn, and do svn export, then copy it to target dir
3. when patching the server with new feature, I can simply go to the target repo/release, and do a git pull?? or should i go with a git patch?

This is how i envision a more simpler life.

Would you guys come up anything much easier than this?

Comment: When you get a chance please do accept some correct answers. You have asked 40 questions and only accepted 1/3 of those. :(

Answer (score 3):

I think you are on the right track. I did something similar.

I have two branches.

```
Master -> holds latest in dev
Production -> holds latest in production
```

When I need to make a change to prod, I branch production branch, make my changes and the merge back in to production branch. This gives me the option to work on multiple features at the same time.

Then I log on to the box and do `git pull`.

Of course the bigger problem here is that with PHP there is no such thing as package like there is java (WAR packages). :( So I am sure this is a pain.

I wish I could help you more but I can't think of anything else to make your life easier.

Comment: I think an easier way to do this is to just setup a git repo/clone on the production server. and from a dev machine, git push to the production server. this way, i don't need to go to the prod server and do a git pull like you suggested.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I do that with tomcat and deploy to remote servers. I think the better idea to even setup hudson and after a successful build to push to the production or some staging server.

Answer (score 0):

install svn on your prod server, checkout a specific branch, lets say production, 
( cd /var/www && svn co svn://domain/path/to/branch )

then once you are ready to push your code just login to prod and run a script that will svn up that specific folder and maybe do some owner updates on the files

( cd /var/www && svn up )
( cd /var/www && chown -R www-data:www-data )
( cd /var/www && svn info )

if you want to do it remotely w/o login to the server you can do remote commands from ssh
(if the script above is on your home and called updateRepo.sh)
ssh user@server updateRepo.sh
if you have your ssh key pair setup you wont even need to do your password 
Note: above will output to bash so you might want to redirect all of this 2>&1

is this helpful?

Comment: yes i would like to do someting like that, but not logging in to the server naymore, i want it to do it on the dev machine. so i would probably go with setting up a git repo on the prod server so i can push from a dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

It may be time to consider using a continuous integration tool like <strike>Hudson</strike> [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

If not, at the very least consider having different branches or repositories for development and production code as per @Amir Raminfar's suggestion.